# How to read bool Data from GridView To Radio List and Change it in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview

I have a grid view that get data about a specific location from table in database
the grid view is displaying like the below

---

|Edit Button |

### ------------

### Select | ID | Title | Flag

### >>>    | 10 | Test  | 0

when I Select a specific row and click on Edit Button there are a new view opened and from it i can change the value like this

Title : (Title TextBox)
Power: (Power Radio List)

i can retrieve my data from GridView to the TextBox, but I Can't Display the bool Data in Radio List
for example: when i click edit i can get the value of title in the title text box like this

```
 Txt_EditTitle.Text = Grd_Reminders.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
```

but i need also the Turn on value return from gridview to shown in my edit page and i can change it to true (on) or false (off)
I tried to do this but not worked:

```
 RdLst_Power.SelectedValue = Grd_Reminders.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
```

as  RdLst_Power is the Radio List name and Grd_Reminders is the grid name

so please if any one can help me and if you need more details iam here

Comment: Your problem is, can't  you turn on or turn off Radio, from code to xaml?

Comment: Please provide your code first.

Comment: I have a Boolean value in database and i shown it in Grid View in the cell no. 2 like this

    MyGrdView.SelectedRow.Cells[2] // for any row selected this cell have a boolean value 0 or 1

The GridView in a View 1 in Multiview control

I need in another View (view2), i can shown this value in radio box or dropdown list, so if the boolean cell in gridview have 0, so in radio button i need first radio to selected and for false i need second radio to selected